# What does "canf" means in fscanf?

Tags: php

> fscanf — Parses input from a file according to a format

> sscanf — Parses input from a string according to a format

To keep Filesystem functions in my mind I need to understand their meanings.

I can guess **the fs** part means filesystem, but ...

### What does **the canf** part mean?

`fopen` and `fwrite` also makes sense. But `fscanf` does not recall anything at all.

Comment: `f` is for __file__, `s` is for __string__. `scan` is __scanning__. last `f` is __formated__.